# SharePoint 2010 Foundation Site Action Ribbon not visible for Site Collection Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, sharepoint-administration

In SharePoint 2010 foundation, suddenly users can not see Site Action menu, new item, edit item etc. ribbon button  are disabled. In list ribbon, only export to excel button is visible.

I am also not able to open site in SharePoint designer, it gives you don't have permissions error. I am the site collection administrator.

This issue is single web application. Other web application in same server working perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you site collection is set to read only. Please check below to find out if SC is read only. Also check if all site collection in this webapplication is read only.

You can check via Central Admin to check LockStatus or you can use powershell to check

Ref link - http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/12/check-lock-status-for-all-site.html